# Cannot see available disk space in LVM

Tags: lvm, iscsi, open-iscsi

I have iSCSI disks connected to my server. i want to resize their capacity. It has LVM on the disk. when i resize the disk in equallogic SAN, i gave it 700GB. and when it check its disk space by fdisk -l, it gives correct size (700GB), but when i run pvscan, it still shows old size(650GB). i have tried to stop iscsi and start again, as well as rebooted the server, but still LVM cannot see the disk size increased, but only fdisk.

Is there any way to referesh the disk size? so LVM Can see it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `pvresize` on the device. It should automatically detect the new size of the iSCSI target and resize the PV. After that point you should be able to use the additional space to expand your logical volumes or create new LVs.

```
pvresize /dev/sdi
```